# IntelliJ Flutter compiler shows inconsistent warnings

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I have different IntelliJ Flutter project.
Some projects show warnings in the "Dart Analysis" tab which other projects don't show.
For example some projects warn to use the const keyword. Other projects don't.
It seems like the compiler is out of date in most projects.
How can I update the compiler?

I've already updated Flutter and Dart in the IntelliJ plugin settings and called "flutter upgrade".

Comment: _I've already updated Flutter and Dart in the IntelliJ plugin settings_ ... Because of that you probably have those warnings. Different versions of flutter/dart needs different approach of Types. So, you should refactoring those portions of code.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was missing lints.
Check out the documentation for Dart & Flutter lints:

[Dart Lints](https://pub.dev/packages/lints)

[Flutter Lints](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints)